# Can anyone explain me "Cross-File Private State" in javascript? Purpose & Implementation?

Tags: javascript

**I read about "Cross-File Private State" here** http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html
Can anyone explain me this snippet of code???

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
var _private = my._private = my._private || {},
    _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function () {
        delete my._private;
        delete my._seal;
        delete my._unseal;
    },
    _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function () {
        my._private = _private;
        my._seal = _seal;
        my._unseal = _unseal;
    };

// permanent access to _private, _seal, and _unseal

 return my;}(MODULE || {}));
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to understand Cross-File Private State or that specific snippet but understanding module pattern depends how good you understand closure. Since there is no access specifier in js but it can be achieved by using closure. An application can have large number of js files and each of these files can expose a method or function or a variable and can simultaneously make any variable,method or function private.

File A.js

```
var a= (function(){
       function _init(){
          _someOtherFunction();
    }
 function _someOtherFunction(){ //private function only accessible in a module 
        // Some code goes here
}
return{
 init:_init
}
 }(a || {}))
```

a is only exposing it's init function but not way _someOtherFunction() will be available.

File B.js
 Defining b and calling function init which is exposed by A.js

```
var b = (function(){
     a.init();    // a.init has been exposed
     a._someOtherFunction  // Code breaks here since _someOtherFunction is unexposed
}(b ||{})
```

Hope it will help you to understand Cross-File Private State

Comment: Thanks a lot for response to my question! i appreciate it! I understand module pattern but the snippet of code in my question was something new for me as new as "Cross-File Private State" topic. Can you explain me this code? Actually i cant understand what is the purpose of _seal and _unseal properties and why we use them in this manner.